# Sharepoint 2016 On-Premise Blank MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a completely blank masterpage for On-Premise with only the ribbon on the page. I don't need any out of the box webparts, only spfx custom web parts and bootstrap.

Can I delete the aspx controls or do I need to wrap in display:none or set visible=false? Also I'm basing this question of the minimal master. Does anyone an example or a style sheet that makes the master page completely blank and is there a way to make the ribbon responsive?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions from github for your reference:

[sharepoint-starter-masterpages](https://github.com/rdrisgill/sharepoint-starter-masterpages)

[SPBones](https://github.com/sprtus/spbones)

Comment: I'm already using that but it's just a minimal masterpage with bootstrap, I want to know what controls I can remove versus which one's I need to hide, I only want the ribbon on the page. everything else will be completely custom. SPBones is def one the best implementations with webpack.

Comment: Yes, we  can hide some controls using CSS style(#divid{display:none;}).